# Why does Make hang when compiling glibc?

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, glibc

I'm trying to build an aarch64 cross compiler to build stuff for my Raspberry Pi 3B. I've been using a helpful script to build gcc for me ([original script](https://gist.github.com/preshing/41d5c7248dea16238b60#file-build_cross_gcc), [mine filled in](https://gist.github.com/TheGag96/8d93fbf8125292b5da6a9e3d40e4548a) - note this contains the versions of libraries I'm using). When building glibc, it makes it to:

```
...
make  subdir=setjmp -C setjmp ..=../ subdir_lib
make  subdir=signal -C signal ..=../ subdir_lib
make  subdir=stdlib -C stdlib ..=../ subdir_lib
make  subdir=stdio-common -C stdio-common ..=../ subdir_lib
```

...and then proceeds to hang indefinitely. I've let the thing sit overnight and it still doesn't complete. `make` just seems to be taking up a whole core, occasionally giving memory back to the OS and taking some again. No `gcc` process or anything is running.

Because it seems that `libc.so` somehow still ended up being built anyway, I tried manually running `make all` in the GCC build folder (`build-gcc`) but I get:

```
checking dynamic linker characteristics... configure: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
```

Unsure if that's related or not.

What's going on here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

- Host OS: Artix Linux x64
- Host gcc: 13.1.1
- make: GNU make 4.4.1

Comment: `make` normally prints commands it executes. Are you suppressing these commands somehow? What is the output from `pstree -p ${pid_of_innermost_make}` ?

Comment: @EmployedRussian It's just make - nothing else.

Comment: It sounds like there is a but in your version of `make`. Try running it without the `-j16` (parallel) flag.

Comment: @EmployedRussian A `make clean` followed by a `make` led to the same thing, unfortunately...

Comment: Update your Make? The latest is 4.4.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oops, I mistyped before - It was 4.4.1, not 4.1.1. Edited my OP.

Comment: Hmm. An idea; build Make from source, run it in a debugger, then pause it when it hangs.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** This is an issue with older glibc Makefiles and Make v4.4+, where the build graph gets perturbed and stdio-common gets continuously re-evaluated and rebuilt. So either downgrade make or upgrade the glibc version to a much newer one.

I am experiencing this with Buildroot and with crosstools-NG as well.

Modifying glibc's Makefile so that `stdio-common` make is traced:

```
# The action for each of those is to cd into the directory and make the
# target there.
$(all-subdirs-targets):
        @if [ "$@" = "stdio-common/subdir_lib" ]; then \
                echo "Running debug command for $@"; \
                $(MAKE) -d $(PARALLELMFLAGS) $(subdir-target-args) $(@F); \
        else \
                echo "Running default command for $@"; \
                $(MAKE) $(PARALLELMFLAGS) $(subdir-target-args) $(@F); \
        fi
```

I could see that the following in the output, signalling the same build is re-executed over and over:

```
 Considering target file '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/bits/stdio_lim.d'.
 File '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/bits/stdio_lim.d' was considered already.
Re-executing[48]: make -d subdir=stdio-common -C stdio-common ..=../ subdir_lib
```

This is happening with subdir_lib, others and subdir_install rules visit to stdio-common, that's why you get a libc.so out as this is all post-build.

Using a less verbose output, we can see (for the stdio-common/others target that some files get restammped and force a rebuild):
I have some more info, from stdio-common/others. It genuinely seems
that .stmp and .st files are being created for every invocation.

```
Re-executing[30]: /usr/bin/make --debug=Makefile subdir=stdio-common -C stdio-common ..=../ others
GNU Make 4.4.1
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Updating makefiles....
  Prerequisite '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/versions.stmp' is newer than target '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/sysd-versions'.
     Prerequisite '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/libc-modules.stmp' is newer than target '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/libc-modules.h'.
    Must remake target '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/libc-modules.h'.
    Successfully remade target file '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/libc-modules.h'.
     Prerequisite '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/dl-tunable-list.stmp' is newer than target '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/dl-tunable-list.h'.
    Must remake target '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/dl-tunable-list.h'.
    Successfully remade target file '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/dl-tunable-list.h'.
     Prerequisite '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/bits/stdio_lim.st' is newer than target '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/bits/stdio_lim.h'.
    Must remake target '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/bits/stdio_lim.h'.
    Successfully remade target file '/home/boran/git/buildroot-2020.02.3/output/build/glibc-2.30-67-g4748829f86a458b76642f3e98b1d80f7b868e427/build/bits/stdio_lim.h'.
Re-executing[31]: /usr/bin/make --debug=Makefile subdir=stdio-common
-C stdio-common ..=../ others
```

I am trying to figure out why...

As a resolution, here's the changed rule that succeeds building it all, but you have to let each step hang first once (apparently, steps hang at a re-run):

```
# The action for each of those is to cd into the directory and make the
# target there.
$(all-subdirs-targets):
        @if [ "$@" = "stdio-common/subdir_lib" ]; then \
                echo "Skipping make command for $@"; \
        elif [ "$@" = "stdio-common/others" ]; then \
                echo "Skipping make command for $@"; \
        elif [ "$@" = "stdio-common/subdir_install" ]; then \
                touch stdio-common/stubs \
                echo "Skipping make command for $@"; \
        else \
                $(MAKE) $(PARALLELMFLAGS) $(subdir-target-args) $(@F); \
        fi
```

Comment: I've also opened up a thread on the glic mailing list libc-users - https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-help/2023-September/006486.html

Comment: And they've come back with this reply, so pointing to this error and workaround https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/1932#issuecomment-1528139734